# python web framework focusing on json-oriented web applications

Tags: python, web-services, json, web-applications

I'm looking for a python equivalent of ruby's [halcyon](http://halcyon.rubyforge.org/) - a framework focused on "web service"-type applications rather than html-page-oriented ones. Google brings up a lot of example code and experiments, but I couldn't find anything that people were using in production and hammering on.

Failing that, what is the best web framework to use for this purpose? I'm looking for something small and lightweight, emphasising robustness and speed rather than features. Also, by speed I simply want a low latency overhead, not the ability to handle thousands of requests per second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on you comment, it sounds like one of the [microframeworks](http://fewagainstmany.com/blog/python-micro-frameworks-are-all-the-rage) may be what you're looking for.

Comment: thanks, will take a good look at them. mnml and web.py both look promising, and the latter seems to have gotten a lot of third-party use.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use django? You can return a json with it, so it's not a problem. At the same time, you get good, well-tested framework...

Comment: django struck me as a bit heavyweight and monolithic - it seems more a rails equivalent, where i'd have to use it for everything or go against its grain. for instance, i'm already using storm as an orm, but i couldn't see any easy way to just swap out django's orm and swap in storm.

Comment: +1: JSON web services in Django works out really well.  Except for authentication, where you do have to roll your own.  But I'd rather roll my own in the Django framework than roll my own from scratch.

Comment: @Martin: As you are already using Storm ORM, you should use frameworks which are ORM-agnostics. Pylons, CherryPy and Flask are some of the options. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Web_application_frameworks#Python_2